# Get 2 results from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

I want to keep track of what pictures users of my Android app like.

I've got one table (in the database) that contains all devices using the app. Users will be able to (optionally) log in to their accounts and of course the likes should be linked to the account then and not to the device. The user can log in on multiple devices and should see the same likes.

Now my `devices` table looks like this:

```
| device_id | associated_user | android_id |
```

Where `associated_user` is the user id if the user has logged in or 0. The `android_id` is a unique string to identify the app instance. `device_id` is just an auto incremented internal key.

And my `likes` table like this:

```
| owner_id | is_user_id | picture_id |
```

`owner_id` would be an user ID if someone is logged in or `device_id` from devices if not.

To get the likes from an android_id I would do the following:

```
 SELECT picture_id WHERE owner_id = (SELECT IF(associated_user > 0, associated_user, device_id) as owner_id FROM devices WHERE android_id='abcdefg' LIMIT 1) AND is_user_id=(SELECT IF(associated_user > 0, 1, 0) as is_user_id FROM devices WHERE android_id='abcdefg' LIMIT 1)
```

But that doesn't seem very efficient.

Is this a reasonable database design or could you think of something more efficient? What would be the best approach to retrieve the likes via the android_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the missing `from` clause is for `likes`:

```
SELECT picture_id 
FROM likes l
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 
              from devices d
              where android_id = 'abcdefg' and
                    ((l.ownerid = d.associated_user and d.associated_user > 0) or
                     (l.ownerid = d.device_id and d.associated_user <= 0)
                    ) and
                    l.is_user_id = (d.associated_user > 0)
             );
```

I do think the logic in the subquery is a bit awkward, both in this case and in your query.  This is simpler and should do the same thing:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 
              from devices d
              where android_id = 'abcdefg' and
                    ((l.ownerid = d.associated_user and l.is_user_id > 0) or
                     (l.ownerid = d.device_id and l.is_user_id = 0)
                    )
             );
```

I have no idea what the purpose of the `limit 1` is, but it runs a big risk in your original version that the two rows being checked are different.  You need an `order by` to guarantee the ordering of rows.

Comment: That works! Thank you. Would that run the subquery for every row in the ``likes`` table?

Comment: @jreuab . . . As the query is formulated, yes it would.

Comment: Hmmm. I was going to propose a slightly different design, but I see that this answer is already accepted. The correlated subquery could be a little expensive, if there are a large number of rows in the `likes` table.

Comment: @jreuab . . . It is better than the version in the original question, which was running two subqueries for each row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, let me clarify this: If I've got millions of entries in the ``likes`` table, would it select both associated_user and device_id a million times?

Comment: @spencer7593 Just go ahead and post your idea, if you can explain to me why that would be better than Gordon's I would accept your answer.